# IE6 printing scrollbars

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-6

I have a page which when printed by one user prints scrollbars for one of the divs in the page. I can't reproduce the problem. Any idea what it might be? If it matters, it's a floating layout, and the page has iframes. Though, the problem occurs with just one div within the frame.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't give a screen shot because of policy. But if the user was printing this page, he'd print everything alright, except the answer below, he'd have scrollbars for that answer's container with the bars taking up the last line and the rightmost couple of characters. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Printing can be troublesome as the user has a lot of control over how things appear. However you could always create (if you haven't already) a CSS for print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

In this document you could set `overflow: hidden;` for the element you mentioned which should remove the scrollbars, but be careful as any content that genuinely requires scrollbars will not be seen.

Comment: Already have one :) Not all of our IE6 users have the problem. Only one user has it - so I'm guessing it might be some browser/print setting.

Answer (score 0):

@media print {
  #scrollbars{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; overflow:visible; width: 70% !Important}
}
without your markup this pretty hard but whatevers:

in the print css, we're going to want to target your rogue div. idk if overflow:visible is needed. i can't see your styles. the marginal sides actually should be placed on the <body> element, but i can't see your shizz.

that should work, but you could always target it with scrollbar...i guess. idk, i've never used scrollbar in conditionals, let alone print. you can't use transparent, i know that. either way: 
you can target it like this

## scrollbars{

scrollbar-base-color:none; 
scrollbar-3dlight-color:none; 
scrollbar-face-color:none; 
scrollbar-highlight-color:none; 
scrollbar-shadow-color:none; 
scrollbar-arrow-color:none; 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:none; 
scrollbar-face-color:none}